# sometimes generic type infer not work. why this happen?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, type-inference

I am using a custom extension method in my C#:

```
//version 1
public static IEnumerable<TSource> ForEachAndReturnSelf<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> container, System.Action<TSource> delegateAction)
{ 
    foreach (var v in container) delegateAction(v); return container; 
}
```

As you might guess, this method is a little tweaked version of this:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<T>.ForEach()
```

The only different thing is that my method returns itself (not void):

Anyway, that version of the method is working fine.
But I have a new version of this method that returns the original type instead of `IEnumerable<TSource>`.
So I changed the method to this:

```
//version 2
public static T ForEachAndReturnSelf<T,TSource>(this T container, System.Action<TSource> delegateAction) where T : IEnumerable<TSource>
{ 
    foreach (var v in container) delegateAction(v); return container; 
}
```

Because I need use it like this:

```
//Example Usage1
List<int> list = /* initialize */;
list.ForEachAndReturnSelf(_ => _ *= 2).Convert(_ => _.ToString()).Sort();

//Example Usage2
list.ForEachAndReturnSelf(_ => _ *= 2)[0] = 4;
```

But when I changed version 1 to 2, all parts of my code using this method now produce a compiler error:

> The type arguments for method
>   `ExtentionMethods.ForEachAndReturnSelf<T,TSource>(this T,
>   System.Action<TSource>)` cannot be inferred from the usage. Try
>   specifying the type arguments explicitly

**The question is:**
I think the type info provided is enough to infer the types, but why can't it?
And how can I satisfy provide the type knowledge so that I can return the same type as the original type provided?

Comment: What is `T`? Where is it defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So firstly your method signature only has 1 generic argument it needs two, so it should look like this

```
public static TCollection ForEachAndReturn<TCollection, TItem>(this TCollection Container, Action<TItem> action)
        where TCollection : IEnumerable<TItem>
{
        foreach (var item in Container)
        {
            action(item);
        }

        return Container;
}
```

Now you will still get the compiler warning you mentioned. This is because it **can** infer the type of your collection. However you're generic constraint saying that `TCollection` must be of type `IEnumerable<TSource>` only works in giving information about `TCollection`. That is why you need to tell the compiler the type of `TSource`. Generic constraints are just that, they are used to constrain, you can't infer the type of the constraint from the thing you are constraining, I imagine that would cause problems potentially. Hence why `TSource` can not be inferred from the generic argument that is provided by `TCollection`.

I hope that makes sense.

Edit: Missed a bit sorry, So to get rid of the compiler warning that you are getting you just need to provide the type information.

```
var myList = new List<string>();

list.ForEachAndReturn<List<string>,string>(i => //do stuff);
```

Comment: first of all, thank you for edit my code and poor Englishes. Your code correction of version 2 is exactly same as what I mean. And I understood your  explanation. So I think the only way left is implement of each container version instead of IEnumerable. (like ForEachAndReturnSelf for List, for [], for Dictionary... overloaded)

Comment: I do apologise I didnt actually answer the final part of you're question. I will edit my answer and hopefully explain how can you do this.

Comment: Thank you for last answer. That seems to be perfect answer for solve this problem. But objective of this tweaked method is like grammar sugar. (using this method instead of foreach...So it can reduce the code lines and the typing duplicated info.). Used many parts of my entire projects and will go on future. So provide type info explicit way is not working as grammar sugar.

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all, you've declared only one generic parameter while you need 2 of them. Change your method's definition to :

```
public static TCollection ForEachAndReturnSelf<TCollection, TItem>(this TCollection container, System.Action<TItem> delegateAction) where TCollection : IEnumerable<TItem>
```

Now to use it you have to include the generic types you're using to call this method like such:

```
meList.ForEachAndReturnSelf<List<int>, int>(i => ... );
```

[Try this online](http://rextester.com/YLIQP57829)